# Can I use this code to login using dialog?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

I got this code in the client side:

```
<p>Username:</p>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="tbUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>

<p>Password:</p>
<p><asp:TextBox ID="tbPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></p>

<asp:ImageButton ID="btnLogin" runat="server"
<p><asp:ImageButton ID="btnLogin" runat="server"ImageUrl="~/Images/LoginButton.png"</p>

<p><asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label></p>
```

And this code in the server side:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = tbUsername.Text;
    string Password = tbPassword.Text;

    usersTableAdapter uta = new usersTableAdapter();
    DsShopping.usersDataTable udt = uta.GetUserByUsername(username);

    if (udt.Rows.Count == 0 || udt[0].Password != Password)
    {
        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMessage.Text = "Error! Login name or password is incorrect.";
        return;
    }

    Session["Login"] = username;
    Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
}
```

The question is how can I pop up a dialog window shows the form and interact using the server side codes and display in the same dialog window that the username or password is incorrect. As shown above I am using asp.net and want to implement the dialog on my html client side.

I should use this exactly (if statement)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11098/Use-Call-RegisterStartUpScript-RegisterClientScrip) is an excellent tutorial to make use of [Page.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx) method.
Use it instead of following line of your code and you should see a `Javascript` alert on invalid user name / password combination.

```
    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    lblMessage.Text = "Error! Login name or password is incorrect.";
```

EDIT: By the way, your password text box (`tbPassword`) should have a `TextMode` property set as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx). `TextBoxMode` enumeration should be used in this case. Read details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textboxmode.aspx)